# is there a python pattern that allows an attribute in a base class be an instance of the derived class?

Tags: python, metaprogramming

Is there some clever way to do this that works?

```
class NamedElement:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
       self.name = Property(name=kwargs.get('name')) #you're going to regret this


class Property(NamedElement):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

myprop = Property(name='myprop') #don't hit enter!!!
```

If anyone wants context, I'm interested in trying to build a UML model in Python .. UML models itself with UML so here I am.

Comment: The base class should not depend on any particular subclass existing. It seems like there should probably be some *other* subclass of `NameElement` that has a `Property`-valued attribute.

Comment: What you have now, though, isn't an error. `Property` doesn't need to be defined until `NamedElement.__init__` is *called*.

Comment: @chepner It's an infinite loop though.

Comment: @chepner the problem is that it's entering infinite recoursion, because `Property.__init__` calls `NamedElement.__init__` which calls the `Property` constructor, but I think you are write about the design here

Comment: i understand what is going on ... i'm trying to figure out a clever way to get the intended effect without creating the infinite loop ... i do have a workaround but it is inelegant

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish exactly? this code does not make sense. couldn't you have a class that contains itself as a property? like a graph

Comment: it's a project for my own amusement ... i am trying to read in the xml that describes the UML metaclasses and create Python classes for those metaclasses ... the class called Property inherits from NamedElement which has an attribute 'name' that is an instance of Property ... see [link](https://www.omg.org/spec/UML/20161101/UML.xmi)

Comment: `self.name = kwargs.get('name')` would avoid the recursion.  past that, no idea what you are trying to do.  this is one of the cases where articulating your expected result might be more informative than your code.  what do you intend your API/data structures to look like?

Comment: I did overlook the infinite loop. But a parent should not depend any particular subclass in any case. (The infinite loop could be avoided, for instance, by having the caller create `Property` instances and passing them as arguments to `NameElement`.)

Comment: @chepner i'm thinking it should be possible to do something like you're describing ... will keep thinking about it

Comment: @JLPeyret i posted a  link to the xml i'm trying to process and tried to describe what i am attempting above ... you can search the xml for 'xmi:id='NamedElement'`  ... i'm quite inexperienced at stackoverflow so please forgive the hamhandededness

Comment: No worries.  But this kinda stuff is a little black magicky in Python, so it would help to know what the end result actually is supposed to look like.  [descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) would be something I'd look at here, maybe.  I have also been having a bit of fun with metaclasses, maybe those can handy.  But we wont know until we see the intended result - I don't see your link btw.  welcome aboard :-)

Comment: It's seems more likely that `NameElement` and `Property` should both be subclasses of some other parent, with a `Property` not being a kind of `NamedElement`, but both classes being examples of some other (abstract) entity.

Comment: The infinite loop is only logical because you created a datastructure of infinite depth and initializing this causes infiite looping. `myprop` is a `NamedElement` which has an attribute `name` which is a `NamedElement` which has an attribute `name` which is a `NamedElement` which ...